# Trying to do a horizontal slide nav with endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to do a regular horizontal nav with arrow that has a endless loop. Tried figuring it out and some how I can't get it to loop back to "all" div.

tried slick carousel but it has this glitch when the page loads

HTML

```
   <div id="second-navigation">
    <div id="slider">
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
      </div>
       </div>
```

JS

```
  var W = $('#second-navigation').width();      
   var N = $('#slider li').length;   
    var C = 0;                          

   $('#slider').width( W*N );        

  $('#left, #right').click(function(){
  var myID = this.id=='right' ? C++ : C-- ;
  C= C===-1 ? N-1 : C%N ;
  $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 1000 );
  });
```

CSS

```
      #second-navigation{
      width:300px;
      height:150px;
      position:relative;
      overflow:hidden;

      }

      #slider{
       position:absolute;
       height:150px;
       left:0; 
       width:9999px;
        }

       #slider li{
       float:left;
        }
```

Comment: `<li>` need to be inside list parent...also, please format your code (and if this was a straight copy-paste: you probably want to start using autoformatting using `prettier` or something in your code editor, too, so your code is always legible)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to as follows:

1. When a direction button (ie left or right) is clicked, clone the list item that will be moved out of view by the animation (ie the first `<li>` for the `<ul>` when the "left" button is clicked)
2. attach the cloned `<li>` to the opposite end of the `<ul>` list (ie append the cloned first to the end of `<ul>` when "left" is clicked
3. animate the margin of the `<ul>` element to hide the original `<li>` that was cloned (ie for the "left" case, animate the `<ul>` left margin to "-150px", which is the width of your `<li>` items)
4. On completion of the animation, ensure the `<ul>` margin is reset, and that the now hidden `<li>` element has been removed

This can be written in code as shown below. There are a few extra things going on here:

- The `<ul>` needs to be the direct parent of `<li>` items (a `<div>` cannot parent `<li>` items)
- [Flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is used to achieve horizontal layout of `<li>` items, which simplifies CSS styling
- Compounded animations need to be prevented (ie the case where button click happens during an existing animation). Below, I'm just ignoring clicks if an animation is underway

```js
$("#left").click(function() {

  /* If currently animated, early exit */
  if($("#second-navigation ul:animated").length) {
    return;
  }
  
  /* Clone the element that will be hidden */
  var firstClone = $("li:first-child").clone();
  
  $("#second-navigation ul")
    .animate({
      /* Animate ul container left margin to left */
      "marginLeft": "-150px"
    }, {
      done: function() {
        /* Reset ul container left margin */
        $(this).css("marginLeft", "0px");
        
        /* Remove element that is now hidden */
        $("li:first-child", "#second-navigation ul").remove();
      }
    })
    /* Add cloned element to end of list */
    .append(firstClone);

});

$("#right").click(function() {

  if($("#second-navigation ul:animated").length) {
    return;
  }
  
  var lastClone = $("li:last-child").clone();

  $("ul")
    .css({
      "marginLeft": "-150px"
    })
    .animate({
      "marginLeft": "0"
    }, {
      done: function() {
        $("li:last-child", "#second-navigation ul").remove();
      }
    })
    .prepend(lastClone);
});
```

```css
#second-navigation {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: left ease-in-out 1s;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, black, transparent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="second-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="left">Move left</button>
<button id="right">Move right</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: when i added to my code somehow its just repeating the last li only then getting other slides. and i have more then unordered list so i make them ids but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you please upload your new code so that I can see what you currently have and help you resolve the new problem